# Error, method cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, bluej

The code is supposed to ask for the number of accidents and determine which of the five regions has the least amount of accidents and print the number of accidents and the region. I'm fairly new to java and I'm having trouble with this error. It says method getNumAccidents in class fourthHomework cannot be applied to given types; required: double found: no arguments reason: actual and formal lists differ in length. How do I fix this issue?

```
import java.util.*;
public class fourthHomework
{
public static void main(String args[]) {
double smallest = 0;
double north = getNumAccidents();
double south = getNumAccidents();
double east = getNumAccidents();
double west = getNumAccidents();
double central = getNumAccidents();

getNumAccidents(smallest);
findLowest(north, south, east, west, central, smallest);


}
public static double getNumAccidents(double smallest) {
System.out.println("Please enter all accidents as positive numbers.");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the amount of accidents: ");
smallest = input.nextDouble();
}

public static void findLowest(double north, double south, double east, double west, double central, double smallest) {
System.out.println("The lowest amount of accidents this year was " +smallest);
if (north == smallest)
{
    System.out.println("The region that had the least amount of accidents was the north.");
}

if (south == smallest)
{
    System.out.println("The region that had the least amount of accidents was the south.");
}

if (east == smallest)
{
    System.out.println("The region that had the least amount of accidents was the east.");
}

if (west == smallest)
{
    System.out.println("The region that had the least amount of accidents was the west.");
}

if (central == smallest)
{
    System.out.println("The region that had the least amount of accidents was the central region.");
}
```

}
}

Comment: The method `getNumAccidents` requires a parameter. You're supposed to pass a value to it when you do `double south = getNumAccidentd()`, same with the other directions. Also, it seems like you forgot to have that method return a value. Lots of problems here

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because in your method getNumAccidents(double smallest) you require a double as a parameter. Where you declare the doubles north, south, east, west, and central you don't add any parameters for the method. You need to add doubles otherwise it would run. Also, since you said that method would return a double, you need to say at the end of the method

```
return smallest
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the beginning of your main method show:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double smallest = 0.0;
    double north = getNumAccidents(smallest);
    double south = getNumAccidents(smallest);
    double east = getNumAccidents(smallest);
    double west = getNumAccidents(smallest);
    double central = getNumAccidents(smallest);
...
```

And in your `getNumAccidents` method, since it is declared as a double, you need to *return* a double value:

```
...
smallest = input.nextDouble();
return smallest;
}
```

This won't fix the program entirely, but it'll help you figure things out as you go along.

Comment: Thank you! When I run it it says the smallest amount of accidents is 0 regardless of what I input. Do you have any advice for that?

Comment: @carrollsoccer5 You can look at main method where it shows  getNumAccidents(smallest);  and have it assigned to the **smallest** variable

Comment: Instead of being equal to zero?

Comment: @carrollsoccer5 Assigning to the **smallest** variable is like this: `smallest = getNumAccidents(smallest);` instead of `getNumAccidents(smallest);` ... then when you run the program you won't see 0 as smallest number of accidents (unless it's an input number) regardless of what you input. You still need to fix the `getNumAccidents` method to request 5 region inputs (instead of 6) and assign the correct lowest value to **smallest** (variable name).

Comment: How do I make it not request 6? Sorry for all the questions, you're helping immensely.

Comment: Part of the issue is that your main method calls `getNumAccidents(smallest)` six times. You could call `getNumAccidents(smallest)` once instead, and set up a for loop inside the `getNumAccidents` method to compare input values. You may have to create more than one variable inside the `getNumAccidents` method. Variables can be used to back up a value once you find a lower value, etc. Try this and see if you come up with anything good, then you can _return_ the smallest value after the loop is done.

Comment: I suggest changing some of your local variables to class variables:  
`public class fourthHomework {
 
 double north;
 double south;
 double east;
 double west;
 double central;
...` right before the `main` method.